# Meteor.publish/Subscribe issue

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

I need to display data to all clients using **Meteor.publish/subscribe**.I did one sample example in that example what i am did is 10 records are inserted at that time of server startup and these 10 records are trying to display to all clients.**The Problem is The data doesn't shows the clients**.I didn't have any idea because i am new to `meteor JS`.So Please see the below code and suggest me how to do?

HTML Code :

```
<head>
  <title>DataApp</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">

         {{#each messages}}      
              {{messages}}
        {{/each}}
</template>
```

ANd JS Code is :

```
Messages = new Meteor.Collection("messages");
if (Meteor.isClient) 
{
 Meteor.subscribe('messages');

}

if (Meteor.isServer) 
{
  Meteor.startup(function ()
  {
    // code to run on server at startup
    for(var i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++ )
    {
      console.log("EXE"+i);
      Messages.insert({ name: "EXE"+i });
     }

  });


     Meteor.publish('messages', function() {

           return  Messages.find();
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are missing a template helper on your template `main`, so make your `Meteor.isClient` look like this:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('messages');

  // this is the template helper that is referenced by {{messages}} 
  // in your template 'main' 
  Template.main.messages = function () {
    return Messages.find();
  };
}
```

Secondly, the handlebars in your html don't make sense, try this instead:

```
<template name="main">
    <!-- inserts value of property 'name' of each object in 'messages'  -->
    {{#each messages}}      
        {{name}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: I have raised a doubt that is " A Record contains Name& Email" so How to show all Records to all clients using Publish/Subscribe.Can you Please give me suggestion?@Tobold

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. You are saying that each message also has a property `Email` and you want to also display it?

Comment: Oh sorry My Question is "A Collection Obj Contains Many Records of each Record contains 5 fields. So can show the Record data with One object using Publish/Subscribe?@Tobold

Comment: Sorry, still unclear. It doesn't matter how many fields are published, you can access all of them in the same way demonstrated by my answer.